# How can CKEditor be used with React.js in a way that allows React to recognize it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ecmascript-6

I've tried using componentWillMount and componentDidMount to initialize CKEditor from within the context of React, but it doesn't seem to work no matter what combination I try. Has anyone found a solution to this besides switching editors?

Comment: This is not exactly what you want, but you should check: https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill

Comment: Thaks  jibees. I came across that myself and it looks like it's my definite fallback option.

Comment: I use it, very happy with it. You should give a try!

Comment: I actually ended up with DraftJS as my solution since Facebook is behind it and it's very unlikely to go anywhere. Thanks for your help jibees!

Comment: Didn't know about this ... https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/ Seems very great, thanks too ;)

Comment: Check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feUYwoLhE_4 very cool indeed ;)

Comment: Draft shows a lot of promise, but still seems very bleeding edge. The documentation is sparse, and trying to use the third party plugins package is even worse in that regard. I have spent many hours trying to get things to work in Draft, and it can be a hair-pulling experience. Some of the docs even refer to npm modules which do not even exist in npm yet. Strange. Simply put, I'm not sure it's ready for prime time outside of Facebook just yet, unless they give it more support.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I published a package on Npm for using CKEditor with React. It takes just 1 line of code to integrate in your project.

Github link - https://github.com/codeslayer1/react-ckeditor.

How to Use?

- Install the package using `npm install react-ckeditor-component --save`.
- Then include the component in your React app and pass it your content and any other props that you need(all props listed on Github page) -

`<CKEditor activeClass="editor" content={this.state.content} onChange={this.updateContent} />`

The package uses the default build of CKEditor but you can use a custom build as well along with any of the plugins you like. It also includes a sample application. Hope you will find it useful.

Comment: That's really cool. Even though I personally no longer need this, I'm going to award you the answer due to the simplicity and MIT license.

Comment: Thanks. I  too stumbled upon this question while trying to integrate CKEditor in my project. Realized that there is no open source package that handles this, so created one.

Comment: This did the job for me.  I was able to get file browsing and uploading going as well.  This package is an honest godsend

Comment: @ZeGregg Nope. Not yet. Will try adding support once CKEditor5 releases a stable build. Its currently in alpha.

Answer (score 16):

Sage describes an awesome solution in his answer. It was a lifesaver, as I've only just started using React, and I needed it to get this going. I did, however, change the implementation, also incorporating Jared's suggestions (using `componentDidMount`). Also, my need was to have a change callback, like so:

Usage of the component:

```
<CKEditor value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

Added this to `index.html`:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Using the following component code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class CKEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <textarea name="editor" cols="100" rows="6" defaultValue={this.props.value}></textarea>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let configuration = {
      toolbar: "Basic"
    };
    CKEDITOR.replace("editor", configuration);
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('change', function () {
      let data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
      this.props.onChange(data);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Again, all credits to Sage!

---

The following is an improved version of the basic version above, which supports multiple CKEditor instances on the same page:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class CKEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.elementName = "editor_" + this.props.id;
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <textarea name={this.elementName} defaultValue={this.props.value}></textarea>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let configuration = {
      toolbar: "Basic"
    };
    CKEDITOR.replace(this.elementName, configuration);
    CKEDITOR.instances[this.elementName].on("change", function () {
      let data = CKEDITOR.instances[this.elementName].getData();
      this.props.onChange(data);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Please note that this requires some unique ID to be passed along as well:

```
<CKEditor id={...} value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the update.

For anyone else reading in the future, I eventually ended up using React-RTE, but changed from that to SlateJS, which is not simply plug and play, but is amazingly versatile.

Comment: Perfect. No more word. Thanks!

Comment: Circling back to this, changed on "`blur`" to on "`change`", as the on "`blur`" didn't account for typing something in CKEditor, then immediately submitting the form (i.e. button click).

Comment: @SanderVerhagen "`change`" events that trigger React updates cause CKEditor to slow to a crawl. I'm looking for a solution that works like "`change`" but is faster.

Comment: @ReedG.Law, I cannot confirm the slowness, but mileage can obviously vary, and improvements are always welcomed!

Comment: @SanderVerhagen it may not be the most elegant solution but I found [jquery-throttle-debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) solved my problem. In the constructor I added `this.onChange = $.debounce(500, this.onChange.bind(this));` and in `componentDidMount` I added `editor.on('change', this.onChange);`. The `onChange` function updates the state of the component with `editor.getData()`.

Comment: Hello all, I need a help to add extraplugins in ckeditor.  I'm trying to add mathType editor plugins using CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'ckeditor_wiris',  'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/ckeditor/', 'plugin.js' ); 
But unable to load extraAllowedContent ... Could you guys please help to solve this problem.
For ExtraAllowedContent i used this:
extraAllowedContent: mathElements.join( ' ' ) + '(*)[*]{*};img[data-mathml,data-custom-editor,role](Wirisformula)'

Comment: Thank you. put <script></script> inside public/index.html, and use window.CKEDITOR instead of CKEDITOR

Answer (score 7):

This is for a React component which displays a P paragraph of text. If the user wants to edit the text in the paragraph, they can click it which will then attach a CKEditor instance. When the user is done altering the text in the Editor instance, the "blur" event fires which transfers the CKEditor data to a state property and destroys the CKEditor Instance.

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';

export default class ConditionalWYSIWYG extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            field_name:this.props.field_name,
            field_value:this.props.field_value,
            showWYSIWYG:false
        };
        this.beginEdit = this.beginEdit.bind(this);
        this.initEditor = this.initEditor.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        if ( this.state.showWYSIWYG  ) {
            var field = this.state.field_name;
            this.initEditor(field);
            return (
                <textarea name='editor' cols="100" rows="6" defaultValue={unescape(this.state.field_value)}></textarea>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <p className='description_field' onClick={this.beginEdit}>{unescape(this.state.field_value)}</p>
            )
        }
    }
    beginEdit() {
        this.setState({showWYSIWYG:true})
    }
    initEditor(field) {
        var self = this;

        function toggle() {
            CKEDITOR.replace("editor", { toolbar: "Basic", width: 870, height: 150 });
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('blur', function() {

                let data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
                self.setState({
                    field_value:escape(data),
                    showWYSIWYG:false
                });
                self.value = data;
                CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy();
            });
        }
        window.setTimeout(toggle, 100);
    }
}
```

The `self.value = data` allows me to retrieve the text from the parent component via a simple ref

The `window.setTimeout();` gives React time to do what it does. Without this delay, I would get an  `Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined`  error in the console.

Hope this helps

Comment: render should be a pure function, so the call to initEditor should be moved out of the render method and instead called inside componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate since the component will have rendered into the DOM by that point. That should also remove the need for the setTimeout call wrapping the CKEditor initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Just refer the `ckeditor.js` in `index.html`, and use it with `window.CKEDITOR`. Don't use `CKEDITOR` straight like the document in React component.

*Just read the first-line of ckeditor.js, you will find what about define of  CKEDITOR.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sage, Sander & co. I just wanted to contribute a version for the "inline" mode of CKEditor.

First, disable CKEditor's "auto-inline" behavior with...

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true
```

Then, for the actual component...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class CKEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.elementName = "editor_" + this.props.id;
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this);
    }

    onInput(data) {
        console.log('onInput: ' + data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div 
                contentEditable={true} 
                suppressContentEditableWarning
                className="rte"
                id={this.elementName}> 
                {this.props.value}</div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let configuration = {
            toolbar: "Basic"
        };
        CKEDITOR.inline(this.elementName, configuration);
        CKEDITOR.instances[this.elementName].on("change", function() {
            let data = CKEDITOR.instances[this.elementName].getData();
            this.onInput(data);
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Usage would be something like this:

```
<CKEditor id="102" value="something" onInput={this.onInput} />
```