# use ckeditor with React

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I am trying to use ckeditor in my React Project but can't figure out some issues. This is what I do:

1. install: `npm install ckeditor`
2. in the React Component, I import ckeditor and use it in componentDidMount:
   `import CKEDITOR from 'ckeditor';`
   ...... 
   `componentDidMount() {
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
   }`

   and the textarea:`<textarea ref="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>`

I got the error:"Uncaught TypeError: _ckeditor2.default.replace is not a function"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can CKEditor be used with React.js in a way that allows React to recognize it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535234/how-can-ckeditor-be-used-with-react-js-in-a-way-that-allows-react-to-recognize-i)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question. I am writing this for anyone stumble upon this when searching for answers. There's a nice official npm package available now. You can install it by `npm install ckeditor4-react`. You can use CKEditor in your code by

```
<CKEditor
    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 4!</p>"
 />
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_react.html)