# ReferenceError: navigator is not defined using ReactJS on Ruby on Rails server side rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, ckeditor5

I am compiling my ReactJS client with `webpack` on a Rails application with ReactJS on Rails. I created a React component that imports the `ckeditor` librairies as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41439980/5764661

After the installation and configuration of `@ckeditor5`, the client is compiled. But when I browse the website on `localhost:3000`, the server side rendering fails on every page with this error:

`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

here is the backtrace:

```
Object../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/env.js ((execjs):121221:17)
__webpack_require__ ((execjs):55:30)
Object../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/keyboard.js ((execjs):121652:12)
__webpack_require__ ((execjs):55:30)
Object../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/uielement.js ((execjs):90071:17)
__webpack_require__ ((execjs):55:30)
Object../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/writer.js ((execjs):90991:18)
__webpack_require__ ((execjs):55:30)
Object../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/view.js ((execjs):90336:15)
__webpack_require__ ((execjs):55:30)
```

My webpack compilation exits in a single chunk

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Where do you run this code? It's this line failing: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/blob/master/src/env.js#L12. Which is rather weird.

Comment: It is a chunk, created by webpack, that is runned in server side rendering. I guess it comes from the fact that the server does not know `navigator`. But from here I don't know how to get further

Comment: We could move that code to a function (so it isn't executed once the module is evaluated). But we'd need to be sure that this is really happening. Do you think you could report a minimal sample of this on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5?

Comment: Sure, I will open an issue with as much details as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor is designed to run on browsers as it's a Javascript Library. As you know, React on Rails integrates Rails with (*server rendering of*) React front-end framework. So by **Server-Side Rendering**, your react component is first rendered into HTML on the server.

**Webpack** bundles the modules and it's served to server first and then to the browser. So `ckeditor` libraries are alien to the server as it's a JS Library. Hence, `navigator is not defined` is thrown.
However `ckeditor` works fine considering Client-Side Rendering as the modules are served to Browser directly.

Due to least usecases, there are a few WYSIWYG editors compatible to run on servers. As of my knowledge, you can have [codemirror-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codemirror-node) as an alternative, which will run on Node.